# Translate Field Value with &#39; to Text String with Single Quote

Tags: sql-server

Sure this is easy but not figuring it out.

I have an SQL table field with a value like "Chauncey`&#39;`s piano".  I want the output of my query to present "Chauncey's piano".  As well, if there are other similar codes in the field value, I want them translated as well.

I've searched and found commands like translate and convert but nothing seems to fit.  Also found similar questions where specific code within the field is being replaced but nothing where the codes are translated in the output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `replace(<your column>, '&#39;', '''')` should work in many DBMS.

Comment: Thanks @stickybit but what I was really looking for is a way to replace any thing like '&#39;'.  I have no way of knowing ahead of time what characters a user is going to type into this Note field.

Comment: You are storing HTML in the database, that's not a good thing for various reasons (security being the biggest one of them). Unescape the data *before* you put it into the table. There's *way* more than `&#39;` that can end up in your data, and way more than can be handled sensibly by SQL.

Comment: @Tomalak this is data behind a vendor's application.  I am not the one storing or securing it.  But I need to get it out into a report and that is why I want to translate it.

Comment: Then translate it in whatever language you are accessing the database with. It will be *much* less hassle than trying to do it with SQL. Most languages have some sort of HTML parsing facility.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option that can help you. It should convert the escape values into their corresponding characters and then convert back to the original type.

```
DECLARE @Sample TABLE( String nvarchar(4000));
INSERT INTO @Sample VALUES ('Chauncey&#39;s piano');

SELECT *, 
    CAST( CAST( String AS XML) AS nvarchar(4000)), --Change nvarchar(4000) for appropriate data type
    CONVERT(XML,String).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') --Jeroen's improvement.
FROM @Sample;
```

Comment: This works if and only if the string also happens to be valid XML, otherwise you can end up with *more* escaped characters than you started with. E.g. `Chauncey&#39;s piano > My piano` will end up as `Chauncey's piano &gt; My piano`, and `Chauncey&#39;s piano < My piano` will end up as a big fat error because `<` must be escaped in XML regardless of context (unlike HTML). While this can be used as a one-shot workaround to patch existing flawed data, fixing the client to supply correct, unescaped values is more worthwhile in the long run.

Comment: The "double escaping" issue can actually be mitigated by using `value` instead of casting: `SELECT CONVERT(XML, 'Chauncey&#39;s piano > My piano').value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')`. Still no solution for text not escaped according to the XML rules, though.